# VS2010 - The referenced component 'X' could not be found. - Disable auto "add reference"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installation, project, compiler-warnings

We have a problem with our project files, which is annoying.

**Example:**

We have a solution with **projX** and **projY**, which reference the assembly **log4net**.

Say, e.g. somebody moves the assembly file and only updates the reference in **projX** + then commits without discovering the missing assembly - then the reference goes missing in **projY**.

The next time I do a checkout and open the solution the **projY** has the reference correctly marked by VS2010 as missing, with a little exclamation mark. So far so good. :)

**Problem:**

Now if I do Build of the solution *then the assembly reference is magically updated in **projY** to point to **projX's** BIN folder!*  (In this case projX has to be build BEFORE projY)

It appears that VS2010 searches our solution tree and adds the assembly automatically if it can find a matching one.

Nice feature, but also a bit dangerous and very misdirecting. For example the assembly might end up having a path which points to another projects bin folder.

**Question:**

Is there any way to disable this behaviour and just get a compile error, which prevents the build?

**Notes:**

- We shifted to using NuGet recently.
- We have defined our own output folder -> files are not placed in Bin\Debug but in ..\output.

[EDIT]

Updated the example for more clearity.

[EDIT]

Searching the web for a solution I found this articale which describes a related problem, where VS2010 also auto adds references but from in this case from the GAC. Our assemblies are NOT in the GAC.  http://blog.scrappydog.com/2010/07/bug-tfs-2010-outsmarts-itself-and-auto.html

[EDIT]

Tried fixing this using a Reference Path in the project. The idea was that VS would search the Reference Path first and project bin folders second. But no luck. It still takes the assemblies from the output folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no known workaround about this.

Comment: Serious :(. I was hoping it was possible somehow to make vs treat the warning as an error and never complete the build this way or simply disable the msbuild auto search and add :/. Dammit! :). But thx for your input :).

Answer (score 1):

I know this might sound stupid, but have you checked your projects Reference paths defined in the project's properties? Maybe its just picking up the missing reference from whatever paths you might have set up.

Comment: Not stupid at all, actually a very sound suggestions. However we have no Reference paths setup in our projects, unfortunatly as that would have been an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with one assembly.

What worked for me was actually moving the whole solution folder to the root of the disk, befor the path to some files was exceeding 256 characters. I learned that when trying to zip/unzip the solution folder.

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed this with other assemblies? I haven't used log4net before but if it is in the [Global Assembly Cache (GAC)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz.aspx) with the right version it could be picked up from there. The GAC is a location for system-wide assemblies to go to be referenced by applications on the system.

Comment: Hi, log4net was just one in many and it's not installed in the GAC. Also the path tends to be the bin directory of another project in our solution (when VS auto finds and adds the assembly). Ex. Imagine that my college moves the assembly from one folder to another and then only updates the reference in 1 of the projects in the solution. Afterwards, when doing a build,  VS discovers the missing assembly for projX, but detects a matching a assembly in projY's bin folder and adds it to projX.